# Append random number of chars to the output of a command

Tags: ruby, bash

I have this command as part of a script that adds timestamp to each line of a command that is being executed:

```rb
$command 2>&1  | tee  >( ruby -pe 'print Time.now.strftime("[%s] ")' >> "$temp_file" )
```

I would like to add an if to this ruby one-line command to check if the output ends with a particular char, and if so, add a random number of that char before writing it to the temp_file.

Something like:

```rb
$line.ends_with?("*") ? puts "#{line}" + "*"*rand(1..10) : puts "#{line}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ruby -ne 'print Time.now.strftime("[%s] ") + $_.sub(/\*$/, "*"*rand(1..10))'
```

I'm using `-n` rather than `-p`, in order to actually *do something* with the value read from STDIN. [From the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby):

```
-n     Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your script,
       which makes it iterate over file name arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk.

             while gets
               ...
             end

-p     Acts mostly same as -n switch, but print the value of variable $_
       at the each end of the loop.  For example:

             % echo matz | ruby -p -e '$_.tr! "a-z", "A-Z"'
             MATZ
```

As for the implementation, I opted to use a regular expression (`/\*$/`) to concisely replace the last character if it matches. Feel free to tweak that as you choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the man page for Ruby it explains `-p`

> `-n` Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your script, which makes it iterate over file name arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk.
>
> ```
> while gets
>   ...
> end
> ```
>
> `-p` Acts mostly same as `-n` switch, but print the value of variable `$_` at the each end of the loop.
>
> ```
> % echo matz | ruby -p -e '$_.tr! "a-z", "A-Z"'
> MATZ
> ```

So `$_` is basically the `$line` variable that you want. By reading/writing this variable you can change the output of your one-liner.

For example, this command adds an exclamation point to the end of each line in a file:

```
ruby -pe '$_ = "#{$_.chomp}!\n"' <myfile
```